# Can I save changes to objects to another TR besides those they are locked?

Tags: versioning, abap, transport, sap-basis

When I try to switch to edit mode for a Report source, a popup comes up telling me

> "A new task will be created for the following request of user XXX".

A transport request is also being suggested.

I don't want to save my changes in this request however, but in another existing one. I am not aware of any versioning systems being implemented in my system, and don't know how to check that.

Is what i'm trying to achieve possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. There are very good reasons for this being an **exclusive** lock -- reasons that you should know about before you attempt to change anything. Briefly speaking

1. The CTS only notes **that** an object was touched, not **what** change was made.
2. When the transport is released, the **entire object** in its current state is exported - there is **no delta/diff logic** involved.

Therefore you can't separately transport changes to the same development object. Furthermore, if you serialize this manually, the second transport will always comprise the changes of the first one.

Things get slightly more complicated with partial objects - you can have `LIMU METH` objects (methods of a class) in different transports, but as soon as you try to lock the `R3TR CLAS` main class, you'll have to resolve that.