# Transport a single method instead of a complete ABAP class

Tags: abap, transport, sap-basis

I developed an ABAP class in SE24 and it is locked in transport request TR1 which was already transported to client.

Now I am making some modifications in this class in another request TR2, this TR will be transported to client only in September.

But meanwhile my client requested to create two new methods in the same class. So I want to transport only those two methods instead of the complete class through TR3.

I can't transport the complete class as the changes I made in TR2 are not complete yet.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not if your description of what has happened is accurate. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089310/can-i-save-modiffications-to-development-objects-report-in-my-case-to-another/21090030#21090030) for some background information. Now, if you only **changed** some method implementation, you could perhaps use `LIMU METH` transport entries to only transport these implementations (although I wouldn't recommend it to avoid side effects). If you **added** some methods - as you said you did -- you will likely have to transport the entire `R3TR CLAS` object, and that will automatically pull all of the changes. Always remember - the CTS only records **that** a change was made to an object, not **what** the change was.

Answer (score -2):

You might be able to use version management to help you here. What you can do is add the new Method to your existing class , make sure its tested etc., generate a version and then delete the 2 methods you do not want to send over. Release your transport and as mentioned above this will extract the class in its current state.

After releasing the transport you can go back and revert to the saved version and your all set.

Later.......

Comment: No, you can’t. Temporary versions are deleted when the transport is released. See the documentation available at http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/57/38e1154eb711d182bf0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm: "You can use these temporary versions to restore the previous version of an object, even while you are developing it. When a request is released, the temporary versions are deleted and replaced by the version active at this time."